# C++ exception on array deletion

Tags: c++

I am making 2 Arrays `a` and `b`

Then I try to assign `a` to `b` and after that I get exception at `delete[] b`, why?

```
void main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *b = new int[3];
    b = a;
    delete[] b;
}
```

Comment: You first leaked the original array `b` then illegally tried to delete the stack-allocated array `a` which you did not `new[]` so you should not try to `delete[]`

Comment: `int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` actually should be `const int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters `b` is not an array. It is a pointer. After this statement

```
b = a;
```

two things occurred. The first one is that the address of the dynamically allocated array

```
int *b = new int[3];
```

was lost.

And the second one is that the pointer `b` now points to the first elements of the array `a` that was not allocated dynamically with using the operator `new`. So you may not apply the operator `delete` to the pointer `b` in this case.

I think you mean copying elements of the array `a` into the dynamically allocated array pointed to by the pointer `b`.

In this case instead of the statement

```
b = a;
```

you should write

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::copy( a, a + 3, b );

//...

delete [] b;
```

Bear in mind that according to the C++ Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    size_t n = 3;

    int *b = new int[n];

    std::copy( a, a + n, b );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << b[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] b;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you `new[]`-ed is not what you pass to `delete[]`. After having the `b = a`, the `b` pointer no longer points to first (original) array element. You need to pass in the original pointer:

```
int* b = new int[3];
int* originalb = b;
// your other code in here
delete[] originalb;
```

That being said don't assign the dynamically allocated `b` to `a`.

Comment: so.. thanks for reply.. and i tried this and it worked.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
 int* a = new int[5];
 int* b = new int[3];
 b = a;
 delete[] b;
 cin.get();
}

Answer (score 0):

When you do b = a, it means that the pointer that's called b, points to the content of a, which is allocated on the **stack**.
When you attempt to delete it, it would obviously fail.